# Linear mapping of lines passing through origin vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I've this question.

Prove that if $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$ is a linear map, then $f$ must map lines passing through the origin vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ to either lines passing through the origin vector or the origin vector in $\mathbb{R}^m$.

I'm not sure how to go about this question. Since $f$ is a linear map, $f(\alpha \bar x+\beta \bar y)=\alpha f(\bar x)+\beta f(\bar y)$. Does $\alpha \bar x+\beta \bar y$ actually denote lines passing through origin in $\mathbb{R}^n$? If so, then that formula itself would be the answer.

Comment: One option is to parameterize an arbitrary line through the origin in $\Bbb R^n$ and compute its image under $f$ (in particular, using linearity).

Comment: So I take $\bar r = \bar v t$ as the parametrized line. Its image will be $f(\bar r)=f(\bar v t)=tf(\bar v)$. Is it obvious that RHS is a line going through origin or origin itself?

Comment: @Tejas Yes because $f(\bar v)$ is a constant vector quantity.  So just rename it $\bar y$ and you have $t\bar y$ -- clearly a line through the origin (or yes, the origin itself if $f(\bar v) = \bar 0$).

Comment: In fact, this shows that we don't need the full strength of linearity for this to be true for a map $f$.

Comment: (And the second possibility is handled when $f(\vec v) = \vec 0$; then the image of the line is just the origin)